# How to infer and save a type from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-inference

There is this very messy API I want to consume, where the values returned are somewhat inconsistent. I could go over every single entry and try and make a type that would cover it, but this would take a very long time, and I wanted to do so programmatically.

My idea would be to infer the types. Let's say I receive this array:

```
const array = [
  {
    title: "test",
    name: "Katy Smith",
  },
  {
    title: ["ACNM", "AAF3"],
    name: "Mary Williams,
  },
  {
    title: "test2",
    name: { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
  },
];
```

I would infer the type with typescript or something else, so it would return the inferred type

```
{
title: string | string[],
name: string | {firstName: string, lastName: string}
}
```

And then I want to save this so I could use it in my project, like fs.writeFile("type.txt". Type). I'm aware that unfortunately typescript doesn't exist at runtime, so this would be impossible.

Are there any other ways I could achieve this?

Comment: How many different types are there? Could you not just make a generic type that handles all cases? Im not sure I understand the question fully sorry. When you want to use these types at the end is there a reason it cant be the type you just pasted above?`{
title: string | string[],
name: string | {firstName: string, lastName: string}
}`

Comment: @DerekLawrence The type there is just an example. In reality there are too many variations and they are more complex, so to get the generic type I would have to go one by one and figure out the possibilities. I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: Do you simply want `typeof`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gWAFAwwDe+hhUAllADYCmAXDAERS3RMA0pZYcAtg2YBpOFDQBlPlQAWnbgF8uBYt3JU6jLEwCCAYQByAWU7Nt2gGIBmJgF0lZGLwGMmhxGgDqFatQr8IcsqK3CTKajSCLGxQAEyBDk6CRDAAZhQI0Pr8kQBSINJgJtRwmdkuACIgtEwwwUFKNgDc+PhiAA60MIYo2kioGDDttCAp8H0oLXhDMAAq0doD3b3IKFhgAK58AEa0CDZYAOSUEQc2+AD052QAegD8QA If so I can write an answer for that, if not then what else do you need?

Comment: Perhaps you need the TS Compiler API...

Comment: @AlexWayne Well, yes, I basically want to generate the type of the object based on all data I have from this API, but I want to save that type so I can use it in my project. Basically I'm gonna be writing the type but programmatically, instead of manually.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand the question but here is a way you could set it up so you could use 1 class for all of your types. But after seeing your last comment Im guessing this is not what you need.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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%202VkikpjiizkSqVJkllxXot6TX1q74aqBa4Gg8GQx5McAQQ2x%20Km0vy8s8zGme1NpknAD8UE9WIgns6nuNPrsPyqgO7UGnWnWj06plhUOgVzIpjrcoVUFWp8cN%20O-Mcgo6AEJUAtcI0IEMXAhi%20H5d0KOYMCgOBBGETpbREUhyjgRNUAAbTsMcKwgCwACIFAwXD0mJR48IAaWCEAoAAZQQVhziIndiLrd4LDQ3C%20AAYRgABZIioA4vgADEAGZcIAXWY-RSIEniYKogB1bA2GBRA0EYjJc0w0VWIEgjgAAJg0kjnDCAwjCcJA8IAKRqc5cH4gVTDwgIaggXDvmYrTaHE6YIPmSEagBAArAZgFKB4IAAd0SWDRGQyQYRkGDkkDTAQ1UMNH0aYJQgsJDcvjRNTQ4QKQrCj1MmispctWHKQmud49nquBrkeYs7CC0KGhuf40DDLqwo62giwKQaerSjKsrq3LOmQornVmeYag4fkanwVZPQAWh23a9s9Yb9CWtAVuZNh1tWKkdhiLltBaxrJmFQ6oGO061o2qlnNu%207Hier5XtW86PoHSALDpH6tBBiA-pmSC3qBza9qRraDpkUbfiAA)